# Como apresentar somente valores pares e impares com três variáveis em C?

Tags: c, for, switch

As minhas variáveis são :

```
    int codigo; --> Sendo esta variável para o switch
    int numero1,numero2,numero3;
```

O usuário irá entrar com três variáveis :

```
         printf("Digite o primeiro numero inteiro: ");
         scanf("%d", &numero1);
         printf("Digite o segundo numero inteiro: ");
         scanf("%d",&numero2);
         printf("Digite o terceiro numero inteiro: ");
         scanf ("%d", &numero3);
```

Após isto, eu preciso fazer com que o programa verifique em cada variável, quais são seus números pares e impares.

Por exemplo, o usuário na primeira variável chamada `numero1` digita o `número 20`, com isto, o programa terá que percorrer até chegar ao `número 20` e mostrar quais números foram pares e impares.

Depois o usuário digita na variável `numero2`, o `número 19`, e novamente irá se fazer a verificação anterior.

Por fim, o usuário digita na variável `numero3`, o `número 30` e novamente a mesma verificação.

Estou usando um switch, pois o usuário terá outras opções também. **Mas como posso fazer isto então ? Usando um `for` junto com um `do-while` até conseguir pegar todos os números e fazer a verificação de quais são pares e impares ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não sei muito sobre C, e não sei se entendi corretamente a pergunta (não posso fazer comentários ainda então não pude perguntar, desculpa )

Fiz esse código para mostrar os números pare, eu normalmente utilizaria apenas 1 variável para isso, mas vc falou que precisava de 3 então resolvi fazer uma função para mostrar os pares dela.

caso queira que o programa liste e separe os pares dos impares, avise que eu modifico

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main (void){
    int numero1;
    int numero2;
    int numero3;
    int count;

    void Par(int valor){
        for(count=1 ; count <= valor ; count++){
            if (count % 2 == 0){
                printf("%d \n", count);
            }
        }
    }

    printf("Digite o primeiro numero inteiro: ");
    scanf("%d", &numero1);
    Par(numero1);
    printf("Digite o segundo numero inteiro: ");
    scanf("%d",&numero2);
    Par(numero2);
    printf("Digite o terceiro numero inteiro: ");
    scanf ("%d",&numero3);
    Par(numero3);

}
```

Comment: Obrigado pelo código, ele funcionou, só modifiquei a sua resposta por que o método estava dentro do main, fazendo com que desse erro.